# How do I use PuTTY to execute commands on my server from a script?

Tags: python, putty

With the `ssh` command one can pass it arguments to tell it to run commands on the remote server.  I am trying to achieve the same thing, but with PuTTY.

I have PuTTY on my Windows machine, installed to `C:`.  I am trying to invoke it from a local Python script, and have it invoke a command `show system info` on the server.

This is the sort of pseudo-Python that I am thinking of:

```
import ssh
server=ssh.Connection(host='10.201.20.240')
result=server.execute('show system info')
```

and more specifically using PuTTY from the Python script, something like this (which is of course not right, otherwise I wouldn't be asking this)

```
command = '"c:\Putty\putty.exe"  -ssh   user@10.201.20.240 -pw admin 10.201.20.240 '
result=command.execute('show system info') 
subprocess.Popen(command)
```

If this were the `ssh` command I would be using `ssh … user@10.201.20.240 show system info` and suchlike.

What is the command-line syntax for the Windows PuTTY program for doing this?

Comment: This question is very unclear as written.  What system are you trying to run python on?  What do you mean by "use python?"  What do you mean by you are not able to run a command?  Is there a specific error message?  Why do you suspect putty is the problem?  Are you sure this question isn't more about windows than linux?

Comment: This is what I understood the questioner to be asking, for what it is worth.

Comment: https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.70/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink